# Jinja 2 does not iterate over my python dict (read from Redis)

Tags: python, django, dictionary, redis, jinja2

API /api/v1/version returns all the version of applications in a specific pod . The return type is an OrderDict. I feed it to my jinja template to display the same on dashboard.

As the number of servers increased, I needed to cache my object in Redis.
Strangely, my jinja2 template doesn't display the dictionary I read from redis.

The only difference I found was the impending 'u' in front of the keys, which was absent in the dictionary I got from redis.

Example:

Dictionary from Redis

```
{'pod1':
"{'server1': {'status': 'failed', 'comment': 'Server is offline.'},
 'server2': {'status': 'failed', 'comment': 'Exception ConnectTimeout while extracting response'}",
'pod2':
"{'server-3':{'status':'success', 'build_number': '74', 'githash': '601a62162ad3cdd2e13f0728f1a9979281acefd4', 'timestamp': '2016-11-17 16:00:01', 'version': '1.0.74-RELEASE', 'tagname': 'release_2016_11_17'}
}"
}
```

Dictionary generated by Django(before caching it)

```
{u'pod1':
    "{'server1': {'status': 'failed', 'comment': 'Server is offline.'},
     'server2': {'status': 'failed', 'comment': 'Exception ConnectTimeout while extracting response'}",
    u'pod2':
    "{'server-3':{'status':'success', 'build_number': '74', 'githash': '601a62162ad3cdd2e13f0728f1a9979281acefd4', 'timestamp': '2016-11-17 16:00:01', 'version': '1.0.74-RELEASE', 'tagname': 'release_2016_11_17'}
    }"
    }
```

The above dictonary is stored in the variable version_details. The line below renders it

```
return render_to_response("version.html", {'pods': version_details, 'teams': APP_DETAILS.keys()})
```

The code snippet below is the jinja2 implementation

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-top">

      <ul class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
          {% for pod, details in pods.iteritems %}
              {% for server,server_details in details.iteritems %}
                  <li class="uk-width-1-3">
                    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-width-large-1-1">
                        {% if server_details.status == 'success' %}
                            <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge uk-badge-success">{{ server_details.status }}</div>
                        {% else %}
                            <div class="uk-panel-badge uk-badge uk-badge-danger">{{ server_details.status }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        <h1 class="uk-panel-title uk-text-bold uk-text-nowrap"><i class="uk-icon-server"></i>{{ server }}</h1>
                        {% if server_details.status == "failed" %}
                            <p class="uk-text-break"><b>Comment:</b> {{ server_details.comment }}</p>
                        {% else %}
                            <p class="uk-text-break"><b>Jenkins Pipeline Number:</b> {{ server_details.build_number }}</p>
                            <p class="uk-text-break"><b>Githash:</b> {{ server_details.githash }}</p>
                            <p class="uk-text-break"><b>Timestamp:</b> {{ server_details.timestamp }}</p>
                            <p class="uk-text-break"><b>Version:</b> {{ server_details.version }}</p>
                            <p class="uk-text-break"><b>GitTag:</b> {{ server_details.tagname }}</p>
                        {%  endif %}
                    </div>
                  </li>
              {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Please let me know if anything is not clear in the above or otherwise if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja2 can't iterate over your `details` because it is not actually a dict, it's a string. You need to deserialize the string so you can iterate over the individual key/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks @knbk . Before asking the question, I just checked type(version_details) to find it to be dict type.

Now looping through the keys, I see all its value are string type.